# Is there any .NET string.format compatible function for Delphi win32?

Tags: delphi, formatting

Is there any .NET string.format compatible function for Delphi Win32 ?

I want to use it's argument order syntax.

I found [one](http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_3909.asp) at delphi3000.com, but it's pretty simple and without supporting number precition, etc.

Don't you know any better open-source implementation ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why you not use the Delphi `SysUtils.Format` function is very complete. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.Format ?

Comment: Of course I'm using Format function. But it can't support changing argument order. It's not useful especially for translating message text into several languages.

Comment: It does support changing argument order: `Format('%1:s - %0:d', [7, 'Text'])`

Comment: Please be more precise about what aspects of the .Net function you're looking for in Delphi. In a comment you mention argument order. Do you also require the brace syntax? The ability to omit type information from the composite format? Arbitrary objects in the argument list?

Comment: @Cosmin, I didn't know about the argument order. I should have checked help before asking.. I use Format as if it is C's printf. Now I'm satisfied with SysUtils.Format :-) Sorry & Thanks for all.

Comment: By the way, should I close this question ? (need self-answering?) Someone voted my question(looking for compatible one by another reason?). I'm not experienced asking here. What should I do in these case ?

Comment: Don't delete the question, looks valuable to me. Compile your own answer from RRUZ's comment and possibly mine and post it *as an answer*. I initially gave a similar answer to RRUZ's comment myself, but immediately deleted it when I saw RRUZ's comment was 9 minutes earlier.

Comment: Thank you for your kindly instruction. I'll follow that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SysUtils.Format.

It also supports *argument order syntax* as string.format in .Net does.

You can change argument order like following example.

> Format('%1:s - %0:d', [7, 'Text'])

---

As I was a C programmer, I thought SysUtils.Format was just like printf in C.

But **[SysUtils.Format](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.SysUtils.Format) is not just like "printf" and it's more powerful** as RRUZ & Cosmin Prund taught me in the comments above. (I should have checked [help](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.SysUtils.Format) ;-)

I wanted .Net's string.format mainly because I wanted to use it's *famous* argument order syntax.

*Argument order syntax* is useful especially for translating message text into languages (like English to Japanese), but I don't need .Net compatibility.

If you had to port .Net's code to Delphi win32, or you are very familiar with .Net's format syntax, these library would be useful if exists, but it isn't in my case.